# Images Glide Firebase Download Issue in Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

I am using the below libraries to pull the images & text in my app from a firebase db using the image url. My app is showing the glide view with images and text however the images are all greyed/white out. Does anyone have an idea what could be the issue?

I am able to upload the images to firebase but when downloading the images the logcat is showing below

```
W/Glide: Load failed for com.google.android.gms.tasks.XXXXXXX with size [1050x600]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There were 3 causes:
java.io.FileNotFoundException(/com.google.android.gms.tasks.XXXXXX (No such file or directory))
java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException(No such file or directory)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
  Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: 
 Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
There was 1 cause:
java.io.FileNotFoundException(/com.google.android.gms.tasks.XXXXXX (No such file or directory))
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
    Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: 
Fetch failed`
```

**this is gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
//buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.checkbox"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    //implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.1'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0') {
        exclude group: "com.android.support" 
   }



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

Context context;
List<ImageUploadInfo> MainImageUploadInfoList;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ImageUploadInfo> TempList) {

    this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_recycler_view_adapter, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ImageUploadInfo UploadInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

    holder.imageNameTextView.setText(UploadInfo.getImageName());

    //Loading image from Glide library.
    Glide.with(context).load(UploadInfo.getImageURL()).into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView imageNameTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageNameTextView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you already have permission for internet in your manifest file? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
`

Comment: Yes, I have the permission for Internet, read and write as well. The code is working when uploading the image to Firebase Storage but not able to retrieve back to my app.